# Replace array value with another value based on keys from other array values

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array `$report`:

```
Array
(
    [03.05.2016] => Array
        (
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [group1] => to change
                )

            [start] => 8:00
            [end] => 16:00
        )

)
```

and a second array `$keys`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 03.05.2016
    [1] => tasks
    [2] => group1
)
```

and a variable `$value` with a value `CHANGED`

I'm looking for a way to change the value of

```
$report[03.05.2016][tasks][group1]
```

so that my final array will be:

```
(
    [03.05.2016] => Array
        (
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [group1] => CHANGED
                )

            [start] => 8:00
            [end] => 16:00
        )

)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you know it is this one that you want to check?

Comment: can you write clearly more? i don't stand your question really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work down through your `$report` variable, assigning by reference to each "step" in your `$keys` array, and then change the final level to your new value.

Edit:
The advantage of this approach is that it will work for any number of levels, although if you will always only have three steps then the answer from @zakhefron is clearer.

```
<?php
$report = [
    '03.05.2016' => [
        'tasks' => [
            'group1' => 'to change'
        ],

        'start' => 8:00
        'end'   => 16:00
    ]
];

$keys = ['03.05.2016', 'tasks', 'group1'];

$value = 'CHANGED';

// Start at the top level of $report
$target =& $report;

// Then work down through the keys
while ($key = array_shift($keys))
{
    $target =& $target[$key];
}

// Finally, set the final target to the new value
$target = $value;

print_r($report);
```

=

```
Array
(
    [03.05.2016] => Array
        (
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [group1] => CHANGED
                )

            [start] => 8:00
            [end] => 16:00
        )

)
```

Comment: Sorry, missed out a &. Fixed it while I tested it and didn't paste it back into the answer. https://eval.in/589556

Answer (score 1):

Try `$report[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]] = $value;`

> Refer : https://3v4l.org/0HBUH

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive function approach here, pass the source, keys and the value to function. It will check if the keys exists in array, if found then call the same function with remaining data, keys and value.

At last keys left empty as all of them searched, now you can simply update the value, and return true, otherwise return false if not found.

```
$report = array(
    '03.05.2016' => array(
        'tasks' => Array(
            'group1' => 'to change'
        ),
        'start' => '8:00',
        'end' => '16:00'
));

$keys = array(
    '03.05.2016', 
    'tasks',
    'group1'
);

$value = 'CHANGED';

function updateValue(&$source, $keys, $value) {
    $keysCount = count($keys);
    if(empty($keys)) {
        $source = $value;
        return true;
    }
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if(isset($source[$key])) {
            array_shift($keys);
            return updateValue($source[$key], $keys, $value);
        }
        else return false;
    }
}

updateValue($report, $keys, $value);
print_r($report);
```

See it working: https://eval.in/589461